# Stopping scroll when dragging on touch devices

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following drag-and-drop list component which works exactly as it should with mouse based events and *should* work that way with touch events but unfortunately while the touch events are starting to drag the list item the screen scrolls at the same time (making the drag pretty ineffectual).

- [component example](http://v24.development.ui-list.divshot.io/demo-sortable-list)
- [github source](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-list)

What i'd like to know is what is the most effect ways to prevent this scroll event from taking place. This code was written using the Ember framework but a JS-specific answer is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the default behaviour:

```
$(".handle").on('touchstart',function(ev) {ev.preventDefault();})
```

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that though here: [preventDefault](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-list/blob/master/addon/mixins/sortable-item.js#L236-L237)

Comment: Actually its funny, your comment forced me to look at the code again and specifically what the event handlers are calling ... that's when I realised that my "preventDefault" code was being skipped over. Urrgh. Well thanks anyway for forcing me to relook at things. :)

Comment: @ken Glade to help you.
It often happens to me to find the solution just sharing my problem.
As you say, it forces to look at the code in a different way...